# Haskell. Опредение типа функции

Tags: типы, haskell

Программировал на Haskell и у меня появился вопрос. Как вручную определить типы некоторых функций в Haskell.
Например, `(.).(.)` и `map.filter`. Понятно, что можно воспользоваться коммандой `:t`, но мне бы хотелось понять, почему

`(.).(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a1 -> a2 -> b) -> a1 -> a2 -> c`

`map.filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [[a]] -> [[a]]`

Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первое,** что нужно осознать, - это эквивалентность инфиксного и префиксного использования операторов. Например, `a + b` эквивалентно `(+) a b`, или `f.g` эквивалентно `(.) f g`.

В частности, ваш первый пример:

```
(.).(.)   ==   (.) (.) (.)
```

Ваш второй пример:

```
map.filter   ==   (.) map filter
```

---

**После этого** можно произвести несколько простых наблюдений:

Наблюдение (1): соотношение типов функции, агрумента и результата.

```
Если:   f :: a -> b
То:     f x :: b
Где:    x :: a
```

Наблюдение (2): функцию двух аргументов можно рассматривать как функцию одного аргумента, которая возвращает другую функцию. То есть:

```
f x y   ==   (f x) y
```

Наблюдение (3): сопоставление переменных:

```
Если:   f :: a -> [a]
        g :: x -> y

То:     f g :: [x -> y]
Где:    a = (x -> y)
```

Здесь, поскольку я использовал `g` в качестве аргумента для `f`, компилятор понимает, что переменная `a` (обозначающая аргумент для `f`) должна быть равна `x -> y` (потому что это - тип `g`).

---

**Разберём ваш второй пример:**

Шаг 1:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
map :: (x -> y) -> [x] -> [y]

Тогда:
    (.) map   ::   (a -> x -> y) -> (a -> [x] -> [y])

Где подстановки:
    b = x -> y
    c = [x] -> [y]

Потому что:
    Аргумент функции (.):   b        -> с
    Тип функции map:        (x -> y) -> ([x] -> [y])
```

Шаг 2:

```
(.) map :: (a -> x -> y) -> (a -> [x] -> [y])
filter :: (z -> Bool) -> [z] -> [z]

Тогда:
    ((.) map) filter  ::  (z -> Bool) -> [[z]] -> [[z]]

Где подстановки:
    a = z -> Bool
    x = [z]
    y = [z]

Потому что:
    Аргумент функции ((.) map):  a           -> x   -> y
    Тип функции filter:          (z -> Bool) -> [z] -> [z]
```

---

Аналогичный разбор для `(.) (.) (.)` я оставлю в качестве упражнения.

Один совет напоследок: читая типы `map :: (a -> b) -> ...` и `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> ...`, помните, что буква `a` в типе `map` - это не то же самое, что буква `a` в типе `filter`. Чтобы в этом не запутаться, разные типы удобнее заменять на разные буквы, как я сделал в разборе выше.

Comment: (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)  я думаю тут ошибка, нужно убрать скобки в (a->c)

Comment: Ошибки нет. Типы `a -> b -> c` и `a -> (b -> c)` эквивалентны (см. Наблюдение 2), но я намеренно поставил там скобки, чтобы заострить на этом внимание.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался!